# Create object from several lists

Tags: python, list, class, object

I am trying to create an object of my class `Member` with entryies of two lists that I have created:

```
class Member:
   __name = ""
   __dayoff = ""

amount = int(input()) #amount of members
peplist = [] #list with all the names
dolist = [] #list with all the days off

for i in range(0, amount):
   print('\n')
   print('type in a persons name please!')
   name = input()
   peplist.append(name)
   daycheck()
```

My function `daycheck()` looks like this:

```
def daycheck():
   print('type in', name, "'s day off, please!")
   dayoff = input()
   if (dayoff == 'monday') or (dayoff == 'tuesday') or (dayoff == 'wednesday') or (dayoff == 'thursday') or (dayoff == 'friday') or (dayoff == 'saturday') or (dayoff == 'sunday'):
       print(name, "'s dayoff is", dayoff, '!!!')
       dolist.append(dayoff)
   else:
       print("I don't know this day! Please try again!")
       daycheck()
```

Now would like to create an object of my class Member() with the attributes `name` and `dayoff` from the two lists, for example:

```
for i in range(0, amount):
   Member[i] = Member(peplist[i], dolist[i])
```

Obviously, this for-loop doesn't work but is there any way to create objects with attributes form lists like that?

Comment: Nit: `dayoff == 'monday' or 'tuesday' or 'wednesday' or 'thursday' or 'friday' or 'saturday' or 'sunday'` is always True...

Comment: @kennytm unless you type in a day that doesn't exist in which case the function will ask you to repeat the process. And if you type in e.g. monday, then it will safe monday in dolist

Comment: I see what you mean now and edited it thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should be closer to what you intent to do:

```
class Member:
    def __init__(self, name, dayoff):
        self.name = name
        self.dayoff = dayoff

peplist = ['A', 'B', 'C']
dolist = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'thursday']

members = [Member(name, dayoff) for name, dayoff in zip(peplist, dolist)]
```

Let's have a look what is inside:

```
for member in members:
    print(member.name, member.dayoff)
```

prints:

```
A monday
B tuesday
C thursday
```

This function `daycheck` will work better:

```
def daycheck(name, dolist):
    days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday','thursday', 'friday',
            'saturday', 'sunday']
    print('type in', name, "'s day off, please!")
    dayoff = input()
    if dayoff.strip().lower() in days:
        print(name, "'s dayoff is", dayoff, '!!!')
        dolist.append(dayoff)
    else:
        print("I don't know this day! Please try again!")
        daycheck(name, dolist)

daycheck('A', dolist)
```

Comment: I get the idea but it is creating this error msg:
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'dayoff'

Comment: Kill me i found a typo! it works now thanks a million!

Comment: your edited func now returns this error msg:
TypeError: daycheck() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'name' and 'dolist'! i got it working by changing daycheck(name, dolist) to daycheck()

Comment: Did you call it like this `daycheck(name, dolist)`?

Comment: I did at first but it returned an error so i tried changing it to daycheck(): with empty brackets and it worked just fine. thanks again